# Adding an image to a scrolling text ticker

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have created a ticker for my project which is working fine.

I want to add up a down arrow image within this ticker as per the stock market.

What should i have to do?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: We would be glad to help you with any programming questions that you may have. This on the other hand does not seem to be one of those questions.

Comment: Post the code of how you generate the ticker and we can help, otherwise we can only speculate.  We don't like speculation though, even though this is a question involving the stock market.

Comment: hii...
i tried to send my code but there is character limitation..how can i send this code..?
n my problem is how to add any small icon with text scrolling within ticker.i just given the example of stock market ticker.

Comment: Without knowing what approach you used to create the ticker, there's not much we can do to help…

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to create the desired image pixel for pixel and stick it just after the stock ticker text.
If you are familiar with QT, there is side scroller code with even alpha-blending. It is based on scrolling a text pixel by pixel. Then it would be rather non-complex to add icons.
Though the stock ticker text and the corresponding icons need to be contained as a block of pixels, so you have to repaint all those pixel-blocks next to each other on every paintevent or timer-tick.

Here is the source code for the side scroller: [Qt - Scrolling the Text in QWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159443/qt-scrolling-the-text-in-qwidget)