# Qt - Scrolling the Text in QWidget

Tags: qt, text, scroll, qwidget

I'm newbie to Qt. Now I'm learning about **Scrolling the Text in a QWidget**.  When my ***text size is lesser than the Widget*** then the text should scroll only once till it reaches the end (text is moved from right to left). once it reaches the left end then again it should start from the right end.  plz help me to do this... Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*Here is my Coding....*

**ScrollText.h**

#ifndef SCROLLTEXT_H
#define SCROLLTEXT_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QStaticText>
#include <QTimer>

class ScrollText : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString text READ text WRITE setText)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString separator READ separator WRITE setSeparator)

public:
    explicit ScrollText(QWidget *parent = 0);

public slots:
    QString text() const;
    void setText(QString text);

    QString separator() const;
    void setSeparator(QString separator);

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);

private:
    void updateText();
    QString _text;
    QString _separator;
    QStaticText staticText;
    int singleTextWidth;
    QSize wholeTextSize;
    int leftMargin;
    int scrollPos;
    QImage buffer;
    QTimer timer;

private slots:
    virtual void timer_timeout();
};

#endif // SCROLLTEXT_H


**ScrollText.cpp**

#include "Widget.h"
#include <QPainter>
#include <QDebug>

ScrollText::ScrollText(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent), scrollPos(0)
{
    staticText.setTextFormat(Qt::PlainText);
    setFixedHeight(fontMetrics().height());
    leftMargin = width();
    setSeparator("   ");
    connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timer_timeout()));
    timer.setInterval(30);
}

QString ScrollText::text() const
{
    return _text;
}

void ScrollText::setText(QString text)
{
    _text = text;
    updateText();
    update();
}

QString ScrollText::separator() const
{
    return _separator;
}

void ScrollText::setSeparator(QString separator)
{
    _separator = separator;
    updateText();
    update();
}

void ScrollText::updateText()
{
    singleTextWidth =  fontMetrics().width(_text);
    timer.start();
    scrollPos = 0;
    staticText.setText(_text + _separator);
    staticText.prepare(QTransform(), font());
    wholeTextSize = QSize(fontMetrics().width(staticText.text()), fontMetrics().height());
    timer.stop();
}

void ScrollText::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    buffer = QImage(size(), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);

    buffer.fill(qRgba(0, 0 ,0, 0));
    QPainter pb(&buffer);
    pb.setPen(painter.pen());
    pb.setFont(painter.font());

    int x = qMin(-scrollPos, 0)+ leftMargin + (leftMargin/2);

    if(x < width())
    {
        pb.drawStaticText(QPointF(x, (height() - wholeTextSize.height()) / 2) + QPoint(0,0), staticText);
        x +=  wholeTextSize.width();

        if(x < 0)
        {
            scrollPos = 0;
        }

        painter.drawImage(0, 0, buffer);
    }
}

void ScrollText::timer_timeout()
{
    scrollPos = (scrollPos+ 2);
    update();
}
```

Comment: Now i can scroll my text when the text size is smaller than the widget. Now, the problem is, if i want to resize my widget then the scroll position has to be moved according to the size of the widget. How can i do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to do this, the easy way, and the hard way.

*Easy way:*

Put a `QLabel` in a `QScrollArea` and scroll the area around, could be controlled by a `QTimer`.

*Hard way:*

Create a custom `QWidget` that scrolls text in its `paintEvent`. The benefit of this would be more control over the rendering, and possibly lower resource usage.

Comment: Yeah i chose the hard way of doing it. Now i can scroll my text when the text size is smaller than the widget. Now, the problem is,  if i want to resize my widget then the scroll position has to be moved according to the size of the widget. How can i do this. Thank you...

Comment: This is why I described it as the hard way! You need to take into account the size of the widget (`QWidget::size()` or `QWidget::rect()`), do the maths and position the text correctly. You could also look at using `QPainter::drawText` with the alignment flags to position the text. Make sure you test your widget with different fonts (faces, sizes, languages) to check that it will work on other computers.

Comment: can u plz explain me with ur code. i just tried it with QWidget::size( ), but i couldnt move the text. plz help me to learn this. thanks...

Answer (score 0):

So, the question is a bit confusing.  It sounds like what you need is more about how to setup a right-to-left word wrap right?

If this is the case, use a QLabel, set its QWidget::layoutDirection property to RightToLeft vs. the default LeftToRight, and set its QLabel::wordWrap property to True.

Comment: i dont want to add a label to my widget. i jus want to write d text in my widget and to scroll the text. i did that all.. now if i'm resizing my widget the text in it is not moving according to the size of the widget. can u plz help me out this. thanks..